# Okta AuthenticationClientBuilder client builder causing app to crash

Tags: android, okta

I have my app calling the AuthenicationClient builder on a button click. This is being tested on a physical Android 12 device.

```
 handler.post(() -> runOnUiThread(() -> authenticationClient = AuthenticationClients.builder()
      .setOrgUrl(getResources().getString(R.string.octa_issuer))
      .build()));
```

Inside grade.build(:app) I have

```
implementation 'com.okta.android:okta-oidc-android:1.0.19'
implementation 'com.okta.authn.sdk:okta-authn-sdk-api:2.0.9'
implementation('com.okta.authn.sdk:okta-authn-sdk-impl:2.0.9') {
 exclude group: 'com.okta.sdk', module: 'okta-sdk-httpclient'
}
implementation 'com.okta.sdk:okta-sdk-okhttp:2.0.0'
```

Error I receive when hitting the button and calling this builder. I have followed every document Okta has and some and just lost at this point. I get this error even without putting the builder on another thread.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.chrobinson.navispherecarrier.dev, PID: 22005
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String; in class Lorg/slf4j/helpers/MessageFormatter; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter' appears in /data/app/~~bfiUKjOLLeBPi-tTbkPssg==/com.chrobinson.navispherecarrier.dev-Bm0xcVwmy5sQv_7p0YZRcQ==/base.apk!classes21.dex)
> at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.debug(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:223)
> at com.okta.sdk.impl.config.OptionalPropertiesSource.getProperties(OptionalPropertiesSource.java:42)
> at com.okta.authn.sdk.impl.client.DefaultAuthenticationClientBuilder.(DefaultAuthenticationClientBuilder.java:117)
> at com.okta.authn.sdk.impl.client.DefaultAuthenticationClientBuilder.(DefaultAuthenticationClientBuilder.java:85)
> at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
> at com.okta.commons.lang.Classes.newInstance(Classes.java:164)
> at com.okta.commons.lang.Classes.newInstance(Classes.java:150)
> at com.okta.authn.sdk.client.AuthenticationClients.builder(AuthenticationClients.java:43)
> at com.chrobinson.navispherecarrier.view.activities.LoginActivity.lambda$onSignIn$6$com-chrobinson-navispherecarrier-view-activities-LoginActivity(LoginActivity.java:208)
> at com.chrobinson.navispherecarrier.view.activities.LoginActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.run(Unknown Source:2)
> at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:7173)
> at com.chrobinson.navispherecarrier.view.activities.LoginActivity.lambda$onSignIn$7$com-chrobinson-navispherecarrier-view-activities-LoginActivity(LoginActivity.java:208)
> at com.chrobinson.navispherecarrier.view.activities.LoginActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda7.run(Unknown Source:2)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:250)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7877)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe this was a library merge issue and this lib `mimeutil` was bringing in different versions than Okta was. I was able to fix the crash by excluding some parts the lib.

```
implementation ('eu.medsea.mimeutil:mime-util:2.1.3') {
exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'
exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-log4j12"
exclude group: "log4j", module: "log4j"
```

}